# Replace ListView with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I replace old Listview with Recylerview?
What changes should I keep in mind when replacing Listview with Recyclerview?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html have very good explanation of of recyclerview with listview. YOu need to change you adapter implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The core of the conversion is the Adapter. Better to have it as library because you don't want to create a new one from scratch every time for a different use case.

So, I've created a **FlexibleAdapter** for all RecyclerView.

Please have a look at the description and full working example: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter

Comment: FlexibleAdapter is great library